# How to get relational fields data in one single query

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I want to optimize the speed of my website and get all data including my relational (pick) fields data in one single query. How to do that?

**Below my findings so far:**

I noticed that when doing `$pod->field('relational_field');` a additional query will run.

Assuming a pod with a **name field** and a **categories field** which is **relational** (pick):

```
// This code below will behave unexpected 
$pod = pods( 'pod', array(
   'where' => array(...),
   'select' => array('t.name', 'category.name AS category_name')
));
```

Assuming that you have created **one single Pod item** linked to two categories, you will get **two results**, because of the category.name AS category_name in the select option. If you had one category assigned to the pod, you will get one result.

The result is as follows:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[2928]
      public 'name' => string 'My pod 1' (length=8)
      public 'category' => string 'Category 1' (length=10)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2929]
      public 'name' => string 'My pod 1' (length=8)
      public 'category' => string 'Category 2' (length=10) // <-- The difference is only in category
```

What I really want is the data of the two categories in that 'category' key as an array. Is that possible?

(originally posted on [Pods.io](http://pods.io/forums/topic/how-to-get-relational-fields-data-in-one-single-query/))

Comment: There is a detailed example of how to use SELECT in Pods fine params here: https://github.com/pods-framework/pods-code-library/blob/master/example/classes/Pods/find/examples/multi-relationship-optimization.php

Comment: Hi @JPollock, Thanks, but that is exactly what I am doing, I get an unexpected result back as you see. Is this a bug? Then I will open an issue on Github if you want.

Comment: Yes, please open an issue. If it's a bug then it belongs in GitHub not SO. BTW best place to get Pods support is Pods Slack. Pods.io/chat

Comment: GitHub issue opened: https://github.com/pods-framework/pods/issues/3061 But it is already closed with the label Support ;-)

Comment: http://pods.io/support http://pods.io/chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close.  The 'select' parameter should be a string as you would supply to a SQL SELECT clause, not an array of fields.  Same with the 'where' parameter, so:

```
$pod = pods( 'pod', array(
   'where' => 'where params as a string',
   'select' => 't.name,category.name AS category_name')
));
```

When you retrieve the data with `field()` or `display()`, use the aliased 'category_name' instead of the dot notation.